# VBA Checkbox to Listbox (uncheck option to remove array)

Tags: vba, checkbox

I am struggling with a simple thing and cannot resolve it. I have a userform that user can populate from a textbox manually. I decided to add a checkbox as well to allow the user to populate the same listbox with a specific list of items. To do it,I made a simple checkbox with array. It works perfectly fine. But obviously keeps adding the items every time you check and uncheck it.

```
Private Sub Checkbox1_Click()

Dim mylist(7) As String

Dim i As Long

mylist(0) = "time"
mylist(1) = "hour"
mylist(2) = "how"
mylist(3) = "test"
mylist(4) = "number"
mylist(5) = "sent"
mylist(6) = "memo"
mylist(7) = "value"


For i = 0 To 7

If CheckBox1.Value = True Then

Finallist.AddItem mylist(i)

End If

Next i


End Sub
```

I can populate the list when the checkbox is checked with the code above, but struggling to remove the array items from the list when the user unchecks the listbox. I simply need to remove the same items from listbox when user unchecks the same checkbox.

I tried the following solution after the code, but seem to be making something very wrong with it, I understand. Just totally stuck....Could someone help me please?

```
If checkobx.value=false then

For i = 0 To 7
For j = 0 To FinalList.ListCount - 1

If InStr(Final.List(j), mylist(i)) > 0 Then
Finallist.RemoveItem mylist(i)

End If

Next j
Next i

end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (explanations in comments and untested):

```
If CheckBox1.Value Then ‘ if checkbox checked
    For i = 0 To 7
         NegKeyList.AddItem interrlist(i)
    Next
Else ‘otherwise
    Dim i As Long

    For i = NegKeyList.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1 ‘ loop through listbox items from last one backwards
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(NegKeyList.List(i), interrlist,0)) Then NegKeyList.RemoveItem i ‘ if current listbox item matches any interrlist array item then remove it from listbox
    Next
End If
```

Comment: Hello, it worked, thank you! Just end i after the else statement and it is perfect. Once again, thanks!

Comment: Thanks again! Done!